# requesting updates using location listener in service is stopping another location listener in activity

Tags: android, android-service, locationlistener

When I requestUpdates in the service using location listener, another listener which I have put in the activity doesn't work. The moment I stop that service (from within the app using toggle button), the activity starts listening for location again. I want both working. Why both are not working simultaneously? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how the requestLocationUpdates( ) function behaves.

**CASE 1: [my case]**
I was using two separate Inner Class implementations of LocationListener, one in the Activity and one in the Service, each requesting for location updates at the same time via requestLocationUpdates(.., .., ..,locationListener) function.

These locationListener objects were not instances of SAME class, so the one who first got used in requestLocationUpdates() function, only it was working.

---

**CASE 2:**
On the second hand, if you call requestLocationUpdates() with instance(**s**) of SAME LocationListener class, all of these work simultaneously.

---

**CASE 3:**
On the third hand :D, if you call requestLocationUpdates() multiple times with one same instance of a LocationListener implementation, the most recent call takes over the previous ones with whatever minTime and minDistance passed in the function.

---

Note: all of above cases are tested on the ***requestLocationUpdates(String provider, int minTime, int minDist, LocationListener listener)*** version of function.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your activity :

```
@Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```